# Upgrading a spell in clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

Will you be able to cook a spell even though you are upgrading it? Im not talking about upgrading the spell factory, only a spell

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can continue to brew spells and train troops while upgrading them in the laboratory. Also, if you have any of that troops or spell in your camp/spell factory when the research completes, they will automatically be upgraded.

Source: personal experience